# What is wrong with my C++ code on codeblocks?

Tags: c++, codeblocks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace;

int main()
{
    string word = " ";

    do
   {
        cout << "Enter a word that has at least 5 characters: " << endl;
        cin >> word;
       }while(word.size() < 5);

        char searchCh = '0';
       cout << "Enter a character and the program will tell " <<
        "you how many times it appears in the word " << word << "." << endl;
        cin >> searchCh;

        int counter = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < (int)word.size(); i++ )
    {
        char ch = word.at(i)

        if(searchCh == ch)
        {
            counter++; //counter = counter + 1
        }
    }

    cout << "The number of " << searchCh << " 's in the word " << word <<  " is " << counter << ".\n";


}
```

I continuously receive multiple errors such as:
'endl' was not declared in the scope
'cin' was not declared in this scope
'word' was not declared in this scope
        'string' was not declared in this scope
        expected ',' or ';' before '}' token

I am using codeblocks, if anyone could answer it would be much appreciated. Thank you:D

Comment: `using namespace;` should be `using namespace std;`

Comment: Not a behavioural change, but your entire for loop could be replaced by a call to `std::count`. As a bonus, it becomes instantly clear that the purpose of this piece of code is to count occurrences of a value.

Comment: Codeblocks is an IDE; this question has nothing to do with any IDE.

Comment: Note that you shouldn't really use `using namespace std;` anyway, because it's bad practice. Drop it before you start writing your first header files!

Answer (score 2):

One of your first lines is

```
using namespace;
```

You probably wanted to write

```
using namespace std;
```

However, please read [Why is using namespace std considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: Regarding that this it is a bad practice: I am not c++ programmer but one can use namespace alias (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace_alias) on libraries that colide it's names with std. 
I personally like to type less.

Comment: @MaLiN2223 I prefer to have my code as explicit as possible. There are of course other ways to deal with the problem, but not being aware of it isn't a solution. Maybe I will try to phrase the answer a bit less subjective

Comment: I do not disagree with you, my habbits from C# are of much weight here. However I just wanted to state the alternative (as you said, not being aware is not a solution at all :P ).

Comment: @MaLiN2223 yeah sure, no offense taken nor intended. Actually thanks for the input :)

Comment: @MaLiN2223, One difference from C# is that `std` is huge, whereas C# namespaces are more manageable.

Comment: @MaLiN2223: Easier typing is not an important goal in programming. Easier **reading** is. Writing `std::` everywhere tends to make code more readable. And I fail to see how namespace aliases avoid the problem with `using namespace` at global scope in header files.